# Demux .mp4 file using openmax and android stagefright

Tags: android, stagefright

how can i demux .mp4 file and separate audio/video and then render individually using openmax and android stagefright.

1.If i have to implement all functions in jni file.

2.what if i use ffmpeg for demuxing,how it can be integrated with android stagefright(if i have to build ffmpeg demuxer as component and link it with android using openmax il or write the entire code in android jni(in that case i have to link ffmpeg with android stagefright)).

3.since android ndk doesn't support stagefright,how to integrate both.

Regards
Mayank

Answer (score 2):

In general, `Android` has all the requisite functions built into it's framework which can be accessed from both `native` as well as `Java` layers. All **component names** below have a `Java` abstraction and `Native` implementation which you can consider using in your project accordingly. For your questions,

1) I would recommend that you could use `MediaPlayer` directly as found in this [`JNI`](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp) implementation, actual implementation of which can be found [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp).

However, should you require to build your own pipeline, I would recommend employing the available blocks such as `MediaExtractor` for demuxing and providing separate tracks, `OMXCodec` for the codecs and I presume you would manage the `audio` routing and `Surface` handling for video in your implementation. A good reference for you could be the [`SimplePlayer`](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp) example implementation.

2)If you wish to employ a `demuxer` from `FFMPEG`, you will have to integrate the same into the list of `MediaExtractors` supported by the system. Since your primary interest is `MP4` and `AVI`, both of which are supported, I feel you can avoid this effort. If you are still interested in the `FFMPEG` integration, please raise a separate query as the answer is quite elaborate.

3) I feel this statement may not entirely be true. `NDK` can support `stagefright` if required, but philosophy is different here. For playback, `NDK` supports an `OpenMAX` `AL` player application as found in this [`html`](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/ndk/docs/openmaxal/index.html#11) file along with an example [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/wilhelm/tests/native-media/jni/native-media-jni.c). However, please note that only `MPEG-2 TS` is supported in `OpenMAX AL` implementation which may not suit your requirements.